# Laravel hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, has-many

I have three tables, `stores`, `store_categories` and `product_categories`. Structure of each table is below

`stores`

```
id  name
1   Mystore
```

`store_categories`

```
id   store_id   product_category_id
1       1            1
2       1            2
```

`product_categories`

```
id   name
1    Grocery
2    Vegetable
```

In my `Store` model, I write the relation

```
public function store_categories(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\StoreCategory');
}
```

So to get all data of a store, I write i `StoresController`

```
$res = Store::with('store_categories')->get(); dump($res);
```

But the dump shows `store_id` and `product_category_id` in relations. How can I display their names( ie store name, product category name etc ) ?

Comment: Did you add the relationships to models?

Comment: I my Store model , I added this funtion public function store_categories(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\StoreCategory');
}

Comment: Why do not you add ProductCateogry relationship and use store_categories as pivot table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add Many to Many relationship as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Store extends Model
{
    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ProductCategory','store_categories','store_id','product_category_id');
    }
}
```

Then you can perform the following:

```
$res = Store::with('categories')->get(); dump($res);
```